# “Undefined control sequence” error for a symbol to `\setbox` while resetting beamer headline

Tags: beamer, errors, themes

In my beamer presentation I wanted to have `infolines` outertheme’s footline and `tree` outertheme’s headerline but with it displaying subtitle instead of title on the first line. So I took `infolines` as outertheme and `\setbeamertemplate[headline]`ed copying `beamerouterthemetree.sty`. It works and compile but I don’t like this gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
\beamer@@tmpl@headline .../foot} \setbox \tempbox 
                                                  =\hbox {\insertsectionhead...
l.108 \begin{document}

--- HELP ---
TeX encountered an unknown command name. You probably misspelled the
name. If this message occurs when a LaTeX command is being processed,
the command is probably in the wrong place---for example, the error
can be produced by an \item command that's not inside a list-making
environment. The error can also be caused by a missing \documentclass
command.
```

Here’s my (stripped/epured) code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\apptocmd{\enumerate}{\justifying}{}{}
\apptocmd{\itemize}{\justifying}{}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}

\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\useinnertheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{bg=darkred,fg=gray!15!white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=darkred,fg=gray!5!white}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshortsubtitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}
      \setbox\tempbox=\hbox{\insertsectionhead}%
      \ifdim\wd\tempbox>1pt%
        \hskip2pt\raise1.9pt\hbox{\vrule width0.4pt height1.875ex\vrule width 5pt height0.4pt}%
        \hskip1pt%
      \fi%
      \insertsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}
      \setbox\tempbox=\hbox{\insertsubsectionhead}%
      \ifdim\wd\tempbox>1pt%
        \hskip9.4pt\raise1.9pt\hbox{\vrule width0.4pt height1.875ex\vrule width 5pt height0.4pt}%
        \hskip1pt%
      \fi%
      \insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\title{My (short) title}
\subtitle{Yet longer and not shortable subtitle}
\institute[SIN]{Long Long Long Long Long Long Institute Name}
\author[S. Name \and S. Name]{Name \textsc{Long} \and Name \textsc{Long}}
\justifying
\begin{document}

\frame[plain]{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Plan}
  \tableofcontents[pausesections,subsectionstyle=shaded]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You seem to need `\newsavebox{\tempbox}`

Comment: Thanks ^^ and thanks again because it works! So ok, originally `\beamer@tempbox` is used, so `\newsavebox`/`\newbox` is probably used somewhere else in the code outside that .sty in order to declare it… But is there any way to use that already defined `\beamer@tempbox`? because even putting all this between `\makeatother` and `\makeatletter` pdflatex report the same error (“undefined control sequence”) separating the (actually undefined) `\beamer` from `@tempbox=` (which is considered as text).

Comment: You should first have `\makeatletter` and then `\makeatother`, not the other way around.

Comment: activating the `@` in `\beamer@tempbox` depends critically where you put the `\makeatletter`.  this can be tricky even for someone with a lot of experience.  in the present example, i'd try putting it right before `\setbeamertemplate{headline}`.

Comment: Oh ok thanks again egreg, that was why it didn’t work in first place ^^" thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate a box, so do

```
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
```

If you want to use Beamer's temporary box register, do

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshortsubtitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}
      \sbox\beamer@tempbox{\insertsectionhead}%
      \ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt
        \hskip2pt\raise1.9pt\hbox{\vrule width0.4pt height1.875ex\vrule width 5pt height0.4pt}%
        \hskip1pt
      \fi
      \insertsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}
      \sbox\beamer@tempbox{\insertsubsectionhead}%
      \ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt
        \hskip9.4pt\raise1.9pt\hbox{\vrule width0.4pt height1.875ex\vrule width 5pt height0.4pt}%
        \hskip1pt
      \fi
      \insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother
```

Note that I fixed the code using

```
\sbox\beamer@tempbox{\insertsectionhead}%
```

which is the correct command, because it is “color aware” and `\setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsectionhead}` isn't.

So, whichever method you choose, use `\sbox`.

Comment: Do you mean you just fixed it in my code sample (I did it too thank you) or there’s a more recent version of TeXlive/wathever which features a beamerouterthemetree.sty where’s the `\setbox[…]=` is replaced with `\sbox[…]{`? Unless so, I’m curious, is there a way to get the official distribution/the right package on CTAN fixed?

Comment: @galex-713 No, I fixed your original code: where it said `\setbox\tempbox=\hbox{` I put `\sbox\beamer@tempbox{`